# HTML5 Web SQL Database INSERT into table fail when hosted from IIS server

Tags: sql, html, iis

The INSERT into table will not work when hosted on a Local IIS 7 server. However it will work when running through the ASP.NET Development Server from Visual Studio 2010. The database and table are created but the INSERT query seems to just do nothing. I'm not getting any error messages back from executing the INSERT query itself and the transaction is not failing. I'm using the Safari browser and Safari's Inspect Element to try and debug the issue. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. See code:

```
try {
    systemDB.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO tblReminders (fldForeignId, fldReminderContent,        fldReminderDate, fldActioned, fldReminderTime, fldSubject, fldDueDate, fldBusinessBaseId, fldMobileRecipientsOnly, fldSendToCoordinator, fldPersonIds) ' +
          'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);', [foreignId, reminderContent, reminderDate, actioned, reminderTime, subject, dueDate, businessBaseId, mobileRecipientsOnly, sendToCoordinator, personIds], dataHandler, sqlErrorHandler);
    }, myTransactionErrorCallback, myTransactionSuccessCallback("INSERT INTO tblReminders:"));
} catch (e) {
    alert(getDatabaseErrorCodes(-1, e));

    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a local web database, the insert should happen. This should be independent of the server.

Q1: What is the error you are getting? 
Q2: Are you opening the database correctly?

The executeSQL method requires the inputs in the following format

```
tx.executeSql(sql, data, resultHandler, errorHandler);
```

I suggest the following as the error callback if you don't have something similar:

```
function errorHandler(transaction, error) {
    log.error("database error", transaction, error);
}
```